# XML Sitemap with typoscript makes wrong URLs

Tags: typo3, sitemap, typoscript, typo3-8.x

According to http://www.typo3-probleme.de/2018/07/11/typo3-sitemap-mit-typoscript-erstellen-2285/ I let TYPO3 V8.7.24 generate the sitemap.xml file. So far it works. But in the file there are not proper URL's. On every URLs end is "?type=500001", for example an URL looks like "https://www.domain.ch/angebot/online-marketing/?type=500001". As a side note , there is also Ext:Realurl in use.

My request is, how can you remove the segment "?type=500001" ? Is the reason typoscript or the extension Realurl? How can I analyse it?

Any hint is welcome. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I've just tested the code snippet in one of my TYPO3 8.7.x instances and it worked fine! There were no `type=500001` GET parameters attached to the URLs. Did you modify the code snippet?

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Good to know that it works properly. I only uncommented the section for tx_news.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the link generation inside of TYPO3. that is configured by typoscript, so you could see typoscript as the culprit.

If you want to know whether realurl (or any other extension) is the culprit: disable the extension in mind. if the error is gone there is a reason to suspect this extension.

When links are generated by TYPO3 it holds some parameter to stay in the current context. Which paramaters should be considered is a configuration (so it is grounded in typoscript).

Have a look (TSOB) at [`config.linkVars`](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=linkvar#linkvars) in general (it is copied implicit to every page object) or of your page object `page.config.linkVars` (in your case: `xml_sitemap.config.linkVars`)

There is a note in the manual:

```
Do not include the type parameter in the linkVars list, as this can result in unexpected behavior.
```

---

Other option would be to explicit set `&type=0` to every link. But don't forget to set `config.uniqueLinkVars = 1` (or `xml_sitemap.config.uniqueLinkVars = 1`)

Comment: Yes i got. There was a line in the main configuration config.linkVars = L(1-2), type. So I changed it for only standard language to config.linkVars = L(0). With that it gets correct URLs without attached "?type=500001". Thank you very much for your hint.